# FASM - x64 vs x86

Tags: if-statement, x86, 64-bit, fasm

I made a simple application in FASM while using windows vista x86. The application compiled and ran fine with no errors what-so-ever.

I then, moved the same exact source code (literally the same files) to my other PC running windows vista x64. Upon compiling the source code I received errors.

When on x86 I could simply start off with:

```
include "win32a.inc"
entry start
```

When compiling on x64 I had to use something similar to the following:

```
format PE GUI 4.0
include "win32a.inc"
entry start
```

---

Another issue (my main concern) is when on x86 I could use:

```
.if dword [var] = "1234"
    ;Do something here
.endif
```

But while compiling the same code on x64 I get "Illegal Instruction" with the following line highlighted:

```
.if dword [var] = "1234"
```

Is there a different way to go about doing this on x64?

Also, how can I code to where it will be compatible on both? I figure, if I compile on x86, then the resulting output will run fine on x64?

Finally, is it possible this could have something other to do with than the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug up some old MASM code to use with the latest version of FASM. I had to add this to use the `.if` macro:

```
include 'MACRO/IF.INC'
```

as well as:

```
include "win32a.inc"
```

for it to compile. Note I get an *Illegal Instruction* error without including `macro/if.inc`.

Maybe the version of `win32a.inc` on your old 32-bit system includes the `.if` macro?